# how to convert this expression generator into an iterator?

Tags: python

I have the following expression generator:

```
chunk_len=max(1,len(v)//parts)
chunks=(
            sortM(v[k:k+chunk_len],parts=parts)
            for k in range(0,len(v),chunk_len)
    )
return multi_merge(*chunks)
```

how can I convert that expression into an iterator?

I tried to follow this example:

[image]

and coded this:

chunks=gen(chunk_len,parts,v))

```
def gen(chunk_len,parts,v):
        for k in range(0,len(v),chunk_len):
            return sortM(v[k:k+chunk_len],parts=parts)
```

but I got the following error:

```
multi_merge() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you notice how the example generator uses `yield`, and yours does not? That's important. `yield` *makes* a function into a generator; without it, it's just a plain function.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to convert the generator into a list, wich is iteratable.

```
chunks=(
            sortM(v[k:k+chunk_len],parts=parts)
            for k in range(0,len(v),chunk_len)
    )

chunks = list(chunks)
```

then the `chunks` is iteratable now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That creates something iterable, which isn't the same as making the `gen()` function an generator (which are also iterable).